# Move exising hg repository into new hg repo, preserving history

Tags: mercurial

I have an existing project being versioned in Mercurial. Lets call it "repo1". Repo1 has some history I want to preserve.

But I've recently decided that I should have versioned repo1's parent directory.

How can I make a Mercurial repository out of the parent, making repo1 part of that project, while maintaining repo1s history. I don't want repo1 to be a subproject. I want it all merged into a single repository.

I've looked at `hg convert`, and `hg export`/`hg import`, but I can't seem to figure out how to make them work for what I want.

I could just copy the repo1 files, trashing the `.hg` folder, then version the lot, but I'd lose repo1's history.

Comment: Perhaps this question ((http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838888/add-additional-changesets-prior-to-changeset-0-zero)) may give you some hints.