# Add additional changesets prior to changeset 0 (zero)?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I have a Hg repository with changeset 0 representing just "adding .hgignore". Starting with changeset 1 I added changesets step by step from a number of Subversion revisions by a script. Then I worked for some time with Hg.

Now I decided that some more Svn revisions will be needed, which are located earlier in history than the beginning revision (changeset 1 in Hg).

Is it possible to insert new changesets between 0 and 1? If yes: How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a *Mercurial to Mercurial* conversion for this. You need to enable the [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) for this. The extension will let you **splice** history together as part of the conversion. This simply means that you can specify new parents for an existing changeset.

So if you start with

```
$ hg glog
@  changeset:   1:aaee9686dedf
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        Martin Geisler <mg@lazybytes.net>
|  date:        Fri Mar 23 15:08:11 2012 +0100
|  summary:     bar
|
o  changeset:   0:17474bd28fe5
   user:        Martin Geisler <mg@lazybytes.net>
   date:        Fri Mar 23 15:08:05 2012 +0100
   summary:     foo
```

You can first import the needed revisions from SVN:

```
$ hg update null
$ run-your-script.sh
```

This will create a second root changeset — you now effectively have two disjoint histories in your repository. I made a single changeset where I added a `baz` file:

```
$ hg glog
@  changeset:   2:515e1292862b
   tag:         tip
   parent:      -1:000000000000
   user:        Martin Geisler <mg@lazybytes.net>
   date:        Fri Mar 23 15:09:19 2012 +0100
   summary:     baz

o  changeset:   1:aaee9686dedf
|  user:        Martin Geisler <mg@lazybytes.net>
|  date:        Fri Mar 23 15:08:11 2012 +0100
|  summary:     bar
|
o  changeset:   0:17474bd28fe5
   user:        Martin Geisler <mg@lazybytes.net>
   date:        Fri Mar 23 15:08:05 2012 +0100
   summary:     foo
```

The final step is to link the histories together: we want 17474bd28fe5 to have 515e1292862b as its first parent. Use `hg log --debug` to see the full changeset hashes and make a slice map file with

```
17474bd28fe535c15c7dad3659994ab048146e99 515e1292862ba2d6776294ffb00c533dc6850c66
```

Then run

```
 $ hg convert --splicemap map.txt your-repo your-spliced-repo
```

You will find the modified history in `your-spliced-repo`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Martin! This works quite nice, but the last step doesn't work. Hg convert tells me that it could not find a particular file (which was added as a largefile; the largefile extension is enabled on user level).

Comment: @ChristophJüngling: aha, it's a largefile? That makes a big difference — the largefiles extension is a very invasive extension. I'm afraid `hg convert` doesn't know about largefiles. Try renaming `.hglf/foo/bar` when you want to rename/include/exclude `foo/bar`. That is, operate on the standin files instead of the files you see in the working copy.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried `hg lfconvert --to-normal` before `hg convert --splicamap ...` and then it works!

Comment: @ChristophJüngling: brilliant! I did not think of converting back to a normal repo first. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Martin, would it be fair to say that using splicemap is essentially the same as `hg rebase`, except the sources of the operation are not altered in the splicemap case?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: not really. Rebase uses repeated merging to iteratively copy changesets from one branch to another (you end up with the combined result). Convert produces a new history directly and the splicemap adjusts the parent pointers directly without taking the file content into account (the spliced changesets wont contain the content from their new ancestors).

Answer (score 1):

As asked: **yes, you can**.

I see at least 3 ways to do it. All - with extensions

Import set of revisions into tip, after import use any of

- Rebase (`rebase -s tip -d X` for each moveable revision, N operations for N revisions)
- Histedit (edit from start-revision, reorder revision in editor-window, 1 operation for N revisions)
- MQ (select all revisions, import to MQ, reorder revisions in patch-stack, edit content if needed, finish all revisions, N+2 operations for N revisions)

I'll prefer MQ as most powerful choice (inside MQ I'll be able to polish former changesets in order to remove conflicts and|or split changes in better way)

Comment: That's good! Would you please explain the three ways to me? :-)

Comment: @ChristophJüngling - added to answer with comments